# Is there a way to customize column headers in w2ui grid to have a search box at the top of each column?

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I am using the w2ui grid framework but would really like to be able to put a search box at the top of each searchable column. It would be the same functionality as the advanced search, except in this different format.

I'm using the newest version of w2ui http://w2ui.com/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it supported out of the box:* No.

*Is it possible:* Probably, depends on your JS skills and your willingness to work around possible side effects.

**A possible approach:**

Since the caption of a w2grid column may contain HTML elements, one approach could be to do something like

```
columns: [ { field: 'field', caption: 'Field <input/>' } ]
```

Then manipulate the input and turn it into a w2field during the grid's (or the column's) render event.

Or simply use the render event to inject other elemets of your choice.

Related w2ui issue: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/583

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a good place to start. I hadn't realized that caption could contain html.